# Window Forms - Window scales down (zooms out) automatically only after connecting to OLEDB

Tags: c#, winforms, oledb

I have downloaded an application example source code, and I changed some of the code that loads Excel file into a DGV. The code is just a quick test and is not part of a productive project.

The code loads data from Excel file into a datagridview control using OLEDB. When the application first executes, it displays the window correctly (at this time no access to excel has taken place).

When the button that performs the load from Excel , to my surprise, when the OLEDB connection is established the currently displayed window is "automatically" re-sized as if you manually zoomed out (as you know, this is not a feature in winforms, but available on web when you press ctrl+shift+minus sign) from it. The data is loaded correctly to the DGV.

The code does not touch the scaling property or any window property at all.

I can't see any logical relationship between the two events. It just makes no sense to me at all.

**Problem**
I don't want this zooming to occur. I can't explain why it is hapening. Your suggestions are appreciated.

**Platform**
I am using VS2015 and Windows 10 on intel 64 machine

**My attempts**
I used debug to locate where the problem occurs. I performed other function like browsing using FileDialog control and it worked. I tried writing text to a label on the window which worked as expected. The problem only occurred after the connection is opened either explicitly or implicitly (by the data adapter)!

**Code**
Below I present part of the code (but I think it does not help!)

```
OleDbConnection objCon = null;
...
    private void cmdReadExcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

                objDS = new DataSet();
                string szConStr = collect_Con(System.IO.Path.GetExtension(txtFilePath.Text), txtFilePath.Text);

                try
                {
                    string dtName = "myExcelFile";
                    objCon = new OleDbConnection(szConStr);
                    //Added the following to ensure that no other code
                    //may have influenced these values
                    //These values are the default anyway
                    this.AutoSize = false;
                    this.AutoSizeMode = AutoSizeMode.GrowOnly;

                    //up to here code works as expected

                    objCon.Open();//*** Zoom out occurs after this line executes!!!!!!!
                    objDTExcel = new DataTable(dtName);
                    string sql =
                     @"select *  from [Sheet1$]";
                    objDA = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, objCon);

                    //*** zoom out occurs here if the connection is not explicity opened!!!
                    objDA.Fill(objDTExcel); 

                    dataGridView1.DataSource = objDTExcel;

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
                finally
                {
                    if (objDA != null)
                    {
                        objDA.Dispose();
                        objDA = null;
                    }

                    if (objCon != null)
                    {
                        objCon.Close();
                        objCon.Dispose();
                        objCon = null;
                    }
                }


            }
```

**Sample images of 2 separate runs:**

[image]

Comment: Probably, somewhere in the code sets properties `AutoSize=true` and `AutoSizeMode=AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink`. Accordingly, when data binding, the size of your controls are adjusted and modified. But it should happen in the line `dataGridView1.DataSource = objDTExcel;`

Comment: On the rights of delirium: maybe JIT reorder the execution of the lines? So it seems that zoom occurs in a different place, and not when you bind the data.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, thanks for your suggestion. I added the 2 settings recommended just before the suspected line but it was not the reason for the issue. Also, the issue occurs immediately after the connection and prior to the biding.

Comment: It may have to do with having to set DPI but I did not re-visit this, maybe someone else needs to know how: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/aa0ec9f6-d645-401d-a223-e2045c3f1704/form-resizes-after-dataset-is-filled?forum=vbgeneral